# ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: -1)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using mariadb and have error

ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: -1)

I'm set max_connection to 1000 and not set max_user_connections in Global and user table.

How can I fix that.

Comment: Quick question: Have you upgraded from MySQL to MariaDB or from an older MariaDB to a more recent MariaDB lately ?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty fix is [FLUSH USER_RESOURCES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html)

> USER_RESOURCES
>
> Resets all per-hour user resources to zero. This enables clients that have reached their hourly connection, query, or update limits to resume activity immediately. FLUSH USER_RESOURCES does not apply to the limit on maximum simultaneous connections. See Section 6.3.4, “Setting Account Resource Limits”.

Since you did not set any user recsource limits, I would suspect a misalignment of columns in the mysql.user table, especially if you performed mysql_upgrade with fixing the grant tables.

To check this run this query

```
select ordinal_position from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='mysql' and table_name='user' and column_name='max_user_connections';
```

I get 40 in MySQL 5.6.

If I upgraded MySQL 5.6 and I don't get 40 from this query, I would just run

```
mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables
```

There is a 6-month-old bug on a similar issue : MySQL Forums :: [Newbie :: ERROR 1226 (42000) at line 1129: User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_updates' resource (current value: 100)](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,617153,617208#msg-617208)